# Deleted row in tableView hide a second tableView in the same controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I've an ***UITableViewController*** within an UITableView(named: **AutocompleteTableView**) that appears only when i'm editing a textfield in the **UITableViewController**.

I draw UITableView(**AutoCompleteTableView**) looking for the coordinates for the second section of my UITableViewController.

I'm scrolling the **UITableViewController** to the second section with :

```
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(1) - 1, inSection:
        1), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
```

After scrolled the ***UITableViewController*** I draw the coordinates for the UITableView(***AutoCompleteTableView***) with :

```
autocompleteTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.rectForSection(1).maxY, self.view.frame.width, (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.rectForSection(1).maxY))
```

So, when I started writing in the textfield, the **AutocompleteTableView** appears in the correct position, but when I ***deleted*** a row from this section, the AutoCompleteTableView never again appears while I start to writing in the TextField.

> I'm calling the two funcs (Scroll, and Draw) in the
>   textfieldShouldChangeCaracter func.

Comment: Are you attempting to position a `UIViewController` (globally) based on the position a section in the parent `UITableViewController`? If so, isn't it a job for the `UIPresentationController`?

Comment: Yes @SwiftArchitect you are right, but the thing is that the application is very complex because lot of vars so We thought the best way to help users to undertstand how  they've to use the application is using the UITableView inside the UITableViewController.

Comment: Please further clarify: post images & code. The sentence *I've an UITableViewController within an UITableView* seems to indicate that you have 2 concurrent `UITableViewController`. Are you tying code to a specific `UITableViewCell`, which are transient?

Comment: I found a solution, the problem was that when the row is deleted from the UITableViewController  the AutoCompleteTableView isn't a subview from the UITableViewController, I addd this code after deleting the row and its works for my : `self.view.addSubview(autocompleteTableView)`